# Can counter/timer run in background?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, background-process

Can i run timer in background. When i minimize game then my timer should be works continue can i do ?

I was try `Application.runInBackground=true;` but it can't works.

```
public class Counter : MonoBehaviour
 {
         public Text counterText;
         private int counterValue;

         // Use this for initialization
         void Start ()
         {
                 Application.runInBackground=true;
                 StartCoroutine ("StartCounter");
         }

         IEnumerator StartCounter ()
         {
                 yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
                 counterText.text = "Counter : " + counterValue.ToString ();
                 counterValue++;
                 StartCoroutine ("StartCounter");
         }
 }
```

Comment: you could use DateTime to find out system time and then use TimeSpan to find out the elapsed time from minimizing to reopening.

Comment: Savlon > This time is define by me don't want to use system time .  have you any other way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found answer of my question.
Special Thanks to Mr.Dinal24.
With the help of Mr.Dinal24 i can get my answer with update some stuff and it's very much helpful to me.

NOTE : THIS CODE WORKS FOR ANDROID AND IOS BOTH (FOR IOS MUST REQUIRED UNITY 4.6.1 OR ABOVE)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Counter : MonoBehaviour
{

        public Text counterText, pauseText, resumeText, msgText;

        private int counterValue, focusCounter, pauseCounter;
        private DateTime lastMinimize;
        private double minimizedSeconds;

        void OnApplicationPause (bool isGamePause)
        {
                if (isGamePause) {
                        pauseCounter++;
                        pauseText.text = "Paused : " + pauseCounter;
                        GoToMinimize ();
                } 
        }

        void OnApplicationFocus (bool isGameFocus)
        {
                if (isGameFocus) {
                        focusCounter++;
                        resumeText.text = "Focused : " + focusCounter;
                        GoToMaximize ();
                } 
        }

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
                StartCoroutine ("StartCounter");
                Application.runInBackground = true;
        }

        IEnumerator StartCounter ()
        {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
                counterText.text = "Counter : " + counterValue.ToString ();
                counterValue++;
                StartCoroutine ("StartCounter");
        }

        public void GoToMinimize ()
        {
                lastMinimize = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void GoToMaximize ()
        {
                if (focusCounter >= 2) {
                        minimizedSeconds = (DateTime.Now - lastMinimize).TotalSeconds;
                        msgText.text = "Total Minimized Seconds : " + minimizedSeconds.ToString ();
                        counterValue += (Int32)minimizedSeconds;
                }

        }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this,

Have a script to check if the application is minimized, To check if the application's state you can use, `OnApplicationFocus`.

```
DateTime lastMinimize;
int timer; // what ever the type you want

// change the value when you game is sent to background
// make sure this is changed before actual minimize happen
public void aboutToMinimize(){
    lastMinimize = DateTime.Now;
}

public void gotMaximized() {
    timer = (DateTime.now - lastMinimize).getMillis();
}
//now use the timer value to reset the timer
```

Comment: Hi Dinal24 > not like that , i have increase value of my counter variable every one seconds. suppose i  put my game in minimize then also that counter will increased in background process.
When i maximize that game then updated counter value will display in my textmesh.

Comment: @SudhirKotila I get your point! this gives the same outcome, this does not increase every second rather it reflects the value that counter should have received by that time. This is more convenient as well.

Comment: @ Dinal24 how can i call these both methods how can i get game is minimized or maximized ?

Comment: @SudhirKotila you can use `OnApplicationFocus` on windows may need to find something for other platforms.

Comment: > Great response from your side. and yea your logic is works successfullyy Thank you so much.

Comment: @ Dinal24  'onApplicationFocus' dosen't work on iOS. its works only in Android.

Comment: Hii, Dinal24 >> thank you . your answer is too much helps for me and onApplicationFocus is successfully works in unity 4.6.1 and above. Thank you once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71229/discussion-between-sudhir-kotila-and-dinal24).